# Find rows where value in column not found in another row

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can't seem to make this SQL query work! I have searched for the answer to this and although some posts come close, they just miss the mark.

Given one table, `Table1`, with columns `Key1 (int), Key2 (int), and Type (varchar)`...

I would like to get the rows where 
     `Type` is equal to `'TypeA'` and `Key2` is `Null` 
 that do NOT have a corresponding row in the table where
     `Type` is equal to `'TypeB'` and `Key2` is equal to `Key1` from another row

So, given the data

```
**KEY1**     **Key2**     **Type**
   1           NULL         TypeA
   2           5            TypeA
   3           1            TypeB
   4           NULL         TypeA
   5           NULL         TypeB
```

I would like to return only the row where Key1 = 4 because that row meets the criteria of Type='TypeA'/Key2=NULL and does not have a corresponding row with Type='TypeB'/Key1=Key2 from another row.

I have tried this and it doesn't work...

```
SELECT t1.Key1, t1.Key2, t1.Type
FROM Table1 t1
WHERE t1.Key2 IS NULL 
    AND t1.Type LIKE 'TypeA'
    AND t1.Key1 NOT IN
        (SELECT Key1
            FROM Table1 t2
            WHERE t1.Key1 = t2.Key2
                AND t1.Key1 <> t2.Key1
                AND t2.Type LIKE 'TypeB')
```

Comment: If you want "Type is equal to 'TypeA'", how would you get the third row?

Comment: confused a bit, Gordon's comment needs answered, and this one : "and Key2 is Null that do NOT have a corresponding row in the table... " If key2 is null then of course it has no corresponding row in key1 unless you have a row with a null value in key1. How does key1 = 3 get returned? It seems to violate every component of your definition. Can you edit your question and reword that line to something a bit more clear?

Comment: Very good points! I can see where the confusion was due to the fact that I had asked for the row where Key1=3 and not what I really want which is where Key1=4. I have edited the question and embellished the description... struggling with the wording and all the while hoping not to add more confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not the biggest fan of where subqueries.

```
select t1.Key1, t1.Key2, t1.Type
from table1 t1
left join table1 t2 
          on t1.key1 = t2.key2 
          and t2.type = 'typeb'
where t1.type = 'typea' 
      and t1.key2 is null 
      and t2.key1 is null
```

I think the logic there is right.  We are taking table 1 where t1.key2 is null and t1.type = 'typea'...left joining it to itself as t2 where t2.type = 'typeb'.  Every time it finds a t2.type b record, we want to omit it, so where t2.key1 (or any t2 field) is null.

Logic make sense?  Give it a run and let me know

Comment: Needs a little more testing on my side due to the amount of data but seems to be a great solution... Thanks Twelfth!