# Exclude rows where value in column not found in another row

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is a followup to a previous question to a previous but in reverse of [Find rows where value in column not found in another row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24769974/find-rows-where-value-in-column-not-found-in-another-row/24787369)

Given one table, `Table1`, with columns `Key1 (int), Key2 (int), and Type (varchar)`...

I would like to exclude any two rows where 
     `Type` is equal to `'TypeA'` and `Key2` is `Null` 
 that have a corresponding row in the table where
     `Type` is equal to `'TypeB'` and `Key2` is equal to `Key1` from another row.

So, given the data

```
**KEY1**     **Key2**     **Type**
   1           NULL         TypeA
   2           5            TypeA
   3           1            TypeB
   4           NULL         TypeA
   5           NULL         TypeB
   6           26           TypeC
   7           NULL         TypeD
   8           NULL         TypeD
```

I would like to return all the rows except where Key=1 and Key=3 because those rows together meet the criteria of Type='TypeA'/Key2=NULL and does have a corresponding row with Type='TypeB'/Key1=Key2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/fffcb/2

```
select a.*
from demo a
left outer join demo b
on 
(
  b.key2 = a.key1
  and a.[Type] = 'TypeA'
  and b.[Type] = 'TypeB'
  and a.Key2 is null
)
or
(
  b.key1 = a.key2
  and b.[Type] = 'TypeA'
  and a.[Type] = 'TypeB'
  and b.Key2 is null
)
where b.key1 is null
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using not exists which should be faster than a left outer join (see: http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2010/03/23/left-outer-join-vs-not-exists/ ).

```
SELECT *
FROM demo d1
WHERE NOT ((TYPE LIKE 'TypeA'
            AND Key2 IS NULL
            AND EXISTS
              (SELECT 1
               FROM demo d2
               WHERE d2.TYPE='TypeB'
                 AND d2.Key2 = d1.key1))
           OR (TYPE LIKE 'TypeB'
               AND Key2 IS NOT NULL
               AND EXISTS
                 (SELECT 1
                  FROM demo d2
                  WHERE d2.TYPE='TypeA'
                    AND d2.Key1 = d1.key2)));
```

You should have indexes on key1 and key2.

```
CREATE INDEX index_key1
ON demo (key1);

CREATE INDEX index_key2
ON demo (key2);
```